# how can i use a template class as another class's typename?

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I have a template class `A`:

```
template<typename T>
class A {
  void test(T & t) {
  }
};
```

now I want a derived template class `B`:

```
template <typename T>
class B {
  B() : a(new T<int>), b(new T<char>) {}
  T* a;
  T* b;
};
```

Is there any method i can implement this?

Comment: What do you mean by `another class's typename`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define `T` as a [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter), e.g.

```
template<template<typename> class T>
class B {
  B() : a(new T<int>), b(new T<char>) {}
  T<int>* a;
  T<char>* b;
};
```

Then you can specify other class template like `A` as the template argument such as `B<A> b;`.

---

BTW: From C++17 you can use keyword `typename` for template template parameter declaration too. i.e.

```
template<template<typename> typename T>
class B {
  B() : a(new T<int>), b(new T<char>) {}
  T<int>* a;
  T<char>* b;
};
```

Comment: /root/hft/external/common/include/core/strategy_container.hpp:16:38: error: expected ‘class’ before ‘T’
 template<template<typename> typename T>     seems not work :(

Comment: @nickhuang Try changing `typename` to `class`, i.e. `template<template<typename> class T>`. [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wdAWicvPY9ED99oI)